# Can I Keep Stage3D From Writing Into the Z-Buffer?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, stage3d

I want to render concealed objects and achieve a similar effect as the one shown in the link in Stage3D.

[Silhouette Effect in Torchlight 2](http://www.max-did-it.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/torchlight_silhouette.png)

I already know how to do this theoretically. I have to draw the object twice:

- Once with normal settings and
- once with a different depth sorting mode where only pixels that are *behind* rendered geometry are shown. *Also*, to prevent weird effects later on, these pixels can't be rendered into the depth buffer.

I can set the correct depth sorting mode in Stage3D with `Context3DCompareMode.GREATER`.
Is it also possible to have Stage3D render pixels into the back buffer, but not the z buffer?

If I can't keep Stage3D from rendering to the depth buffer, the effect will look like this:

[Glitchy Silhoutte Effect](http://www.max-did-it.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/glitchy.png)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can turn off depth and stencil buffer. Check context3d.configureBackBuffer method.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone comes across this, there are two things you should be aware of:

1) As Volgogradetzzz make sure you have a stencil/depth buffer as part of your backbuffer using `Context3D.configureBackBuffer(...)`

2) If you need to turn on or off depth pixel writing at different moments you can use set the depthMask argument in this function:

```
public function setDepthTest(depthMask:Boolean, passCompareMode:String):void
```

A little strange to find this feature in a function of this name, as depth write masking affects the results, not the test itself.